# How can retrieve bitbucket repositories when db is demolished?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

My bitbucket server db is demolished, so I have no bitbucket data. how Can I retrieve repositories?

Bitbucket is running but it can't connect db.

Answer (score 1):

If you log on to the bitbucket server, and locate the directory where Bit Bucket installed its data files. It's usually:

```
/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/data
```

You can find where the data files are in:

```
cd /opt/atlassian/[version]/bin/
grep BITBUCKET_HOME= *
```

Then there should be a folder called 'repositories'. Each of the numbered folders in there is a git repository.